# opening a batch file that opens a text file in python

Tags: command-line, python-3.x

I am writing a script that can execute a batch file, which needs to open a file in the same folder first. My current code is:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen("Mad8dl.bat <RUNTHISTO.txt>", cwd=r"C:\...\test")
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

where the `...` is just the path to the folder. However, everytime I run it I get the syntax error:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

Any help regarding the syntax would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably remove the < and > angle brackets from your code; just pass the filename, without any brackets, to your batch file. (Unless your filename really does contain < and > characters, in which case I really want to know how you managed it since those characters are forbidden in filenames in Windows).

Second, your code should look like:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(["Mad8dl.bat", "RUNTHISTOO.txt"], cwd=r"C:\...\test", stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Note the list containing the components of the call, rather than a single string. Also note that you need to specify `stdout=PIPE` and `stderr=PIPE` in your Popen() call if you want to use communicate() later on.